# Test abruptly ends

Tags: java

```
 straight = true;
    for(int i = 1; i < rankCount.length && straight; i++) {
        if(rankCount[i] ==1) {
            for(i = i+1;i < i+2; i++) {

                if(rankCount[i]!=1){ 
                    straight = false;

                }
            }     
        }     
    }
```

I am implementing video poker in java, and I am using this piece of code to figure out if the current hand is a straight hand. I first iterate through a List of cards, and update the index of the rankCount array to the corresponding current card. For example, if the iterator on the list of cards give me an ace, I rankCount[1]++. Now to figure out if the hand is a straight hand I simply look for the first index of ArrayCount with an entry one, and then the code posted is self explanatory. However, when I test the program the program abruptly ends without an error. In fact, it ends precisely after exiting the outer loop. and removing the above piece of code solves that problem.

Answer (score 4):

Your inner loop is using the same loop counter as your outer loop. Don't.

```
for(i = i+1;i < i+2; i++) {
```

I think you wanted something like,

```
boolean straight = true;
for (int i = 0; i < rankCount.length; i++) {
    if (rankCount[i] != 1) {
        straight = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: got it. Just out of curiosity, whats wrong with using the same loop counter for the inner loop.

Comment: Outter I resets because of inner I. They're the same I.